# Gaussian simultenous scan with two variables

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am trying to rigid scan two bond distances simultaneously in Gaussian 09/16. For example, I have taken a water molecule and started a rigid scan. Below is my input.

```
# b3lyp/6-31+g(d,p) scan

Title Card Required

0 1
 O              
 H                  1            B1
 H                  1            B2    2            A1

   A1           109.50000006

B1 0.96 S 20 0.1
B2 0.96 S 20 0.1
```

The output scan plot is this:

[image]

It is a 3D plot of 441 (21 steps for H1 atom * 21 steps for H3 atom) grid points. I want both the H atoms to move simultaneously, so I get a 2D plot of only 21 points. Below is the type of plot I want for scanning 2 H atoms. Any help with the input?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's certainly easy enough to try: use a single variable for both bond lengths.

Comment: That seems fine, though. However, I would be thankful to you if you please share any sample input.

Comment: In your z-matrix substitute B2 with B1 and delete the last line before the mandatory blank line.

Comment: it works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the obvious hints @Martin provided, it became easy. We can simultaneously scan only one coordinate. So, for this particular problem the input should be as follows,

```
# hf/3-21g scan

Title Card Required

0 1
 O              
 H                  1            B1
 H                  1            B1    2            A1

   A1           109.50000006

B1 0.96 S 20 0.1
```

Explanation: Since bond the bond lengths of OH are same, one has to put only B1 parameter in the z-matrix and vary that parameter.
But, for a special case, if $OH_1\neq OH_2$ then this will not work.
I will look for more general case and post that as update here.

Comment: In my opinion don't bother looking for a more general case. Gaussian interface is not flexible enough for that. There is possibly an easier way to generate a series of xyz coordinates programmatically with python of so and run single points on these. For future questions like these, I recommend looking at [mattermodeling.se].

Comment: Oh... I forgot, you might have luck with GIC. But in all honesty, learning python is probably easier...